# I'm trying to put the latest record into a link from mysql while using Yii framework

Tags: php, yii

I'm getting the latest record so I can store it into a path.

```
 $currentid = Yii::app()->db->createCommand("select id from content where id = (select max(id) from content)")->queryRow();
 Yii::app()->session['announcement_message'] = 'You have successfully created an announcement.';
 $url = Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl('announcement/view/id/'.  $currentid);
 $this->emailAll($url);
```

And this is passed into my email function:

```
public function emailAll($url)
{
    $this->set_mail_settings();
    $message = new YiiMailMessage;        
    $emails = Yii::app()->db->createCommand("SELECT group_concat(email) as em FROM persons WHERE party_id != 184")->queryRow();
    $email_ids = explode(",",$emails["em"]);
    $message->setBcc($email_ids);
    $message->setBody('To view, click here: '.$url);
    $message->subject = 'New Announcement Posted!';
    $message->addTo('no-one@nowhere.com');
    $message->from = Yii::app()->params['adminEmail'];
    Yii::app()->mail->send($message);                      
}
```

But when I receive the email link, instead of giving me the id# of the last record, it gives me "array"

announcement/view/id/Array.

I need it to be the exact id number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. `Queryrow` always return array. So you have to use as below.

```
$url = Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl('announcement/view/id/'.  $currentid["id"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the first value of the first row then just use "`->queryScalar()`" instead. Less hassle :)

Answer (score 0):

You can order your sql statement, then select 1. It should be quicker than doing a subquery.

```
 $currentid = Yii::app()->db
              ->createCommand("select id from content ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1")
              ->queryRow();
```